# Calculate average value in VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, math

I need to calculate the average value of different numbers in VBA, but it has become complicated and I'm not sure what to do next.

I turned to Google to find potential solutions to my problem, however I didn't find anything relevant.

Here is my table:

[image: Table example]

Each ID:

- ...is a non-unique number.
- ...has an associated Value.

The average values for each ID need to be calculated in VBA.

Example

- The values with an Id of 'ID1' are 2,3 and 4, and so have an average of 3
- The values with an Id of 'ID2' are both 4, and so have an average of 4
- ...

What I have now either calculates average value for a whole column or simply  repeats the value.

I would be very grateful for help and advice.

Comment: Hi. Have you considered using a pivot table to do this? Just change value field setting to 'Average' when you drag in the value column...

Comment: @wilson88 Thank you. I'll try to use it. But according to my task, i need to do this in VBA. I have a several calculations which i have made in VBA and this one should be also a part of it.

Comment: Hi, You can write VBA to create pivot table as suggested by @wilson88 and add the vlookup formula using VBA which will pull the average from pivot table to your desired column.

Comment: I would suggest that you show your efforts so far.  With code your way more likely to get help from the folks you want help from.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's easy enough with formula to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fair enough. If you have your heart set on a VBA solution this one should do the trick (for your example)...

```
Sub Av()

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

    Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A2:A" & LastRow), Range("A" & i), Range("B2:B" & LastRow)) / _
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & LastRow), Range("A" & i))

Next

End Sub
```

This solution will preserve your table rows in the example you posted (as non unique by ID)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very for this. It works perfect. Now I can end with my calculations :)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to use a pivot table as wilson88 suggest you could try the following,

Create a list from your data set that has no duplicates ID in it.

In the column next to this list you can do a sumif formula to get the sum from you data set of each ID.

Then in the column next to this you can do a countif formula to count the number of times that user id appears. Then you can divide the sumif column by the countif column to get the average.

Once you get the idea of this you can combine the formulas into one cell as the following

=sumif("ID RANGE","ID","sum Range")/Countif("ID_RANGE","ID")

This would be the manual way to produce a pivot table, you Can use vba to produce the formula's.

Sheet1.range("A1:A100").value = "=enterformulahere"

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the array formula to find the unique id's

Im using id's in a1:a10 and my values in b1:b10

Using this array in d1:d10

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$10),0))`

Gives me the unique ID's, then as above, simple SUMIF/COUNTIF

`=SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,$D1,$B$1:$B$10)/COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,$D1)`

[image]

Hope this helps